# Representable gem: trouble handling nested documents (hashes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mapping, representable

I'm using the Representable gem and am following the instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/apotonick/representable#document-nesting) for accessing properties in a nested document.

Representer and test:

```
# app/representers/nhl/game_representer.rb

require 'representable/hash'

module Nhl::GameRepresenter
  include Representable::Hash
  include Representable::Hash::AllowSymbols

  property :stats_id, as: :eventId

  nested :venue do
    property :venue_id, as: :venueId
  end
end

# test/models/nhl/game_test.rb

class Nhl::GameTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context 'initializing w/Representer' do
    should 'map attributes correctly' do
      real_hash = {
        :eventId => 1553247,
        venue: {
          :venueId=>28,
          :name=>"Air Canada Centre"
        }
      }

      game = Nhl::Game.new.extend(Nhl::GameRepresenter).from_hash(real_hash)

      assert_equal 1553247, game.stats_id
      assert_equal 28, game.venue_id
    end
  end
end
```

Here the first assertion passes but the second one (venue) fails. It seems that my `nested` block just isn't doing anything because `game.venue_id` ends up being `nil`.

Looking back at the readme, I realized it says:

> "Note that ::nested internally is implemented using Decorator."

...and the code example uses `Class SongRepresenter < Representable::Decorator`. So I rewrote my representer like this:

```
class Nhl::GameRepresenter < Representable::Decorator # <--- change to class
  include Representable::Hash
  include Representable::Hash::AllowSymbols

  property :stats_id, as: :eventId

  nested :venue do
    property :venue_id, as: :venueId
  end
end
```

In my test, I then set up the `game` object like this:

```
game = Nhl::GameRepresenter.new(Nhl::Game.new).from_hash(real_hash)
```

However, I'm still getting the same problem: `game.venue # => nil`

Can anyone with more experience using this gem point out what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I have something similar to what you have in your last example (i.e. creating a `Representer` class that inherits from `Representable::Decorator`, and I observed the same behavior. To make sure it wasn't user error, I commented out all of the hash-related logic and changed to json, and then called `from_json` and `nested` properties were stored as expected.

I'll open a Git issue unless one already exists.